# How to reference to another object in Java?

Tags: java, object

I'm doing an homework question, and not sure what is wrong with my code. The question is: http://prntscr.com/1xe4gd.

My code so far:

```
public class Person //This is the class
{
    String firstName;
    String familyName;
    boolean isFemale;
    String partner;
}
```

My method so far is:

```
Person getAngelinaJolie()
    {
        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.firstName = "Angelina";
        person1.familyName = "Jolie";
        person1.isFemale = false;
        person1.partner.firstName = "Brad";
        person1.partner.familyName = "Pitt";
        return person1;
    }
```

When I compile, error says "cannot find symbol - variable firstName". Could anyone please help me with this. Not sure why it cant find the symbol.

Comment: The member "partner" is of type String and not Person. Since String type doesn't have firstName attribute, the compiler is complaining. You should declare "partner" as Person for your use case.

Comment: I think the Person instance returned should have isFemale set true too...

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `String partner;` in class Person, but I suppose you mean `Person partner;` then you will be able to set it's properties after `person1.partner = new Person();` of course

here is the proper code:

```
Person getAngelinaJolie()
    {
        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.firstName = "Angelina";
        person1.familyName = "Jolie";
        person1.isFemale = true;

        person1.partner = new Person();
        person1.partner.firstName = "Brad";
        person1.partner.familyName = "Pitt";
        person1.partner.isFemale = false;

        person1.partner.partner = person1;

        return person1;
    }
```

Comment: @blueJavaMAN maybe because you havent filled all fields in partner, also I suppose Angelina isFemale = true, at least as I remember her :)

Comment: Could you show us the complete output?  I suspect that "no exception message" is just part of the output, and that there's something that provides more information about the reason for the failure (like `NullPointerException`).

Comment: Yup, as I suspected.  It's trying to reference something that's `null` (probably `person1.partner`).  "No exception message" probably means no **additional** info was added when the exception was thrown.  However, I can't tell what line is Q1E.java line 12; you'll have to figure that out since you have the source file.  If it's the line with 'person1.partner.firstName = ' on it, then you have to first set `person1.partner = new Person()` as Ilya   said.  If you did that and you're still getting NullPointerException, please tell us what line it's on.

Comment: @blueJavaMAN and this codes tells nothing :( check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Person //This is the class
{
    String firstName;
    String familyName;
    boolean isFemale;
    Person partner;
}
```

and the same method now

```
Person getAngelinaJolie()
    {
        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.firstName = "Angelina";
        person1.familyName = "Jolie";
        person1.isFemale = false;
        person1.partner.firstName = "Brad";
        person1.partner.familyName = "Pitt";
        return person1;
    }
```

now `person.partner.firstname` will refer to the already defined Person partner in Person